# Rails / Jquery best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I'm building a database of food recipes in Rails, and I'm trying to build a handy form to add ingredients using Jquery.

My associations:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

My recipe form looks like this (simplified):

```
<%= simple_form_form(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <fieldset><legend>Ingredients</legend>
      <table class="table">
        <% @recipe.recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>
          <tr>
            <%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients, recipe_ingredient do |dif| %>
              <td><%= dif.text_field :ingredient %></td>
              <td><%= dif.text_field :amount %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Ingredient</a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Two questions:

1. Does my .each block look correct for the associations?
2. What's the best way to add a new row to that table client-side so that the form helper recognizes the new row and creates the appropriate db insert?  I'm not quite clear on how Rails magic works in terms of creating an array of objects like that.

Comment: Do you want to create ingredients while creating a recipe or add the existing ingredients to recipe?

Comment: @SybariteManoj you're right, it makes quite a difference. As to question #2, just a hint : [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @m_x yes, if he wants to add new ingredients then nested_attributes are way to go, but in that case there is no need of `many-many` association as ingredients will always be created. But if he wants to add the existing ingredients then `ingredient_ids` can be used. And in the last case when he wants both then he might need to use combination of the previous approaches. :)

Comment: I don't want to create new ingredients, but I do want to assign existing ingredients to the recipe using the recipe_ingredients join table.  I neglected to mention that my Recipe model has an accepts_nested_attributes_for call.  Added that to my original question.

Comment: I should add that I pretty much understand how associations work, and I'm about 99% sure I have these set up correctly.  What I don't yet have a grasp on is how to set up a form to reflect those associations.  Normally I would create an array in the form field names and do the object-building logic in the controller, but it seems like Rails probably has this covered already iff I set up the form fields correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Ryan Bate's [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) is the way to go, it has support for simple_form also

Basic usage:

`<%= simple_nested_form_for @recipe do |f| %>`

Then where you want your "Add new ingredient" link to appear:

`<%= f.link_to_add "Add new ingredient", :recipe_ingredients %>`

The gem itself has good documentation, also check the Wiki pages.